# Implement XOR/Cycle Swap Linked List Reverse approach in java

Tags: java, linked-list, reverse, xor, xor-linkedlist

I understood this concise way of reversing linked list from source **["BlogSpot - Reverse a linked list using only 2 pointers"](https://p--np.blogspot.com/2011/04/reverse-linked-list-using-only-2.html#comment-form)** and I tried to convert this into Java but getting logical error. Can any one provide me with correct implementation ?

> **C++ version**

```
while(q)
{
    q = (List*) ((int)p ^ (int)q ^ (int)q->next ^ (int)(q->next=p) ^ (int)(p=q));
}
head = p;
```

> **Java Version**

Below approach is wrong.

```
while(q!=null)
{
    q = new ListNode(p==null?0:p.val ^ q.val ^(q.next==null?0:q.next.val)^((q.next==null?0:(q.next.val =p.val)))^(p.val=q.val));
}
```

Comment: You can't do this in Java.

Comment: Java doesn't have pointer arithmetics like C (and C++). You can't meaningfully XOR two references.